# rosdep install fails with ament_pep8: No definition of [python3-pep8] for OS version [32] on Fedora 32, deprecated

Tags: ros2, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fedora 32 replaced `python3-pep8` with [python3-pycodestyle](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1839789#c1) so the following step from [Install dependencies using rosdep](https://index.ros.org//doc/ros2/Installation/Dashing/Linux-Development-Setup/#install-dependencies-using-rosdep) fails:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro dashing -y --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps libopensplice67 libopensplice69 rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 urdfdom_headers"
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
ament_pep8: No definition of [python3-pep8] for OS version [32]
```

I tried to install the Fedora 31 version of python3-pep8 and got more dependency issues:

```
dnf install https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/31/Everything/armhfp/os/Packages/p/python3-pep8-1.7.1-4.fc31.noarch.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 1:16:46 ago on Thu 13 Aug 2020 11:52:19 AM EDT.
python3-pep8-1.7.1-4.fc31.noarch.rpm                                                             426 kB/s |  63 kB     00:00
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python(abi) = 3.7 needed by python3-pep8-1.7.1-4.fc31.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.7dist(setuptools) needed by python3-pep8-1.7.1-4.fc31.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Any work-around available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359471/rosdep-install-fails-with-ament_pep8:-no-definition-of-%5Bpython3-pep8%5D-for-os-version-%5B32%5D-on-fedora-32,-deprecated/) by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2020-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to the [Fedora Robotics mailing list](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/robotics@lists.fedoraproject.org/message/N7GCMDHTZC45IJSBJ67XOLHROECJMYKE/) I got around this. The full command looks like this:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro dashing -y --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps libopensplice67 libopensplice69 rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 urdfdom_headers python3-pep8"
```

However the next command, `colcon build --symlink-install` fails, so I started [another thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/359578/colcon-build-symlink-install-cant-find-__main__-module-ld-cannot-find-lpthreads/).

---

Originally posted by [RobbieTheK](https://answers.ros.org/users/57728/robbiethek/) with karma: 43 on 2020-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0